# Pass a value from a FieldType to another

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently building a Form to send messages to other users in the system i'm developing, the body of the messages can be built based on Templates. A screenshot of it: i.imgur.com/eFI1I.png

My problem comes when i try to load the templates to apply them to the new message. I load the template through an Entity Type. Here's the code:

```
->add('plantillas', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'UCA\SGExaBundle\Entity\Plantilla',
    'property' => 'nombre',
    'expanded' => true,
    'required' => false,
```

The rest of the Form is here: https://gist.github.com/4372276

The Controller code is here: https://gist.github.com/4372282 (I'm sorry for the messy code, I've tried to apply different solutions)

The Template Entity has these properties:

- Id
- Nombre
- Contenido

All templates are rendered in the Form as a list of checkboxes, showing property Nombre. The thing is, i want the value of the property Contenido from the selected template to transfer to the Field Type named Cuerpo as soon as the user selects one of the elements in the list (clicks on a checkbox) (also in the URL gist.github.com/4372276).

Truth is i ranout of ideas, i was thinking on doing the submit in the button "Elegir Plantilla", updating the value of the variable mnj that is linked to the FormType of the message. However, even with the submit the value in the Body doesn't refresh. I guess i have to apply some method to refresh it but i don't know which one. Anyways i think that's not an efficient solution.